# python plot inconsistent result with essentially same code

Tags: python, plot

I have the below codes. They should essentially mean the same but the output is completely different. I have tried debugging but fails. (drop NaN, force use index as xaxis).

```
df.cumpnl.plot()
plt.show()
```

and

```
plt.plot(df.cumpnl)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

I have also added a summary description of the dataframe as below:

```
                GLD          GDX          USO       spread  moving_average  \
count   2033.000000  2033.000000  2033.000000  2033.000000     2019.000000   
unique          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN             NaN   
top             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN             NaN   
freq            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN             NaN   
mean     138.444161    24.877939    82.818234     4.947196        4.936297   
std       24.804896     6.822558    31.199880    11.654489       11.282190   
min      100.500000    11.713412    17.040001   -26.767277      -24.238099   
25%      118.129997    20.289474    65.540001    -1.851543       -2.149600   
50%      126.139999    23.060490    84.959999     3.581103        3.482795   
75%      164.919998    30.179216    98.720001    10.767963       10.545780   
max      193.889999    42.812782   166.559998    46.173454       33.801446   

        moving_std_dev   upper_band   lower_band long_entry long_exit  \
count      2019.000000  2019.000000  2019.000000       2033      2033   
unique             NaN          NaN          NaN          2         2   
top                NaN          NaN          NaN      False     False   
freq               NaN          NaN          NaN       1511      1043   
mean          2.696286     7.632582     2.240011        NaN       NaN   
std           1.618263    11.343639    11.451420        NaN       NaN   
min           0.419066   -22.795539   -27.101549        NaN       NaN   
25%           1.564900     0.601110    -4.709357        NaN       NaN   
50%           2.397069     5.720233     1.190496        NaN       NaN   
75%           3.396123    12.700594     8.270555        NaN       NaN   
max          13.845905    41.026057    29.988603        NaN       NaN   

        positions_long short_entry short_exit  positions_short    positions  \
count       2019.00000        2033       2033      2018.000000  2018.000000   
unique             NaN           2          2              NaN          NaN   
top                NaN       False       True              NaN          NaN   
freq               NaN        1548       1029              NaN          NaN   
mean           0.39574         NaN        NaN        -0.376115     0.019822   
std            0.48913         NaN        NaN         0.484529     0.878659   
min            0.00000         NaN        NaN        -1.000000    -1.000000   
25%            0.00000         NaN        NaN        -1.000000    -1.000000   
50%            0.00000         NaN        NaN         0.000000     0.000000   
75%            1.00000         NaN        NaN         0.000000     1.000000   
max            1.00000         NaN        NaN         0.000000     1.000000   

        spread_difference          pnl       cumpnl  
count         2032.000000  2017.000000  2017.000000  
unique                NaN          NaN          NaN  
top                   NaN          NaN          NaN  
freq                  NaN          NaN          NaN  
mean             0.004847     0.050814    36.617689  
std              2.203791     1.976904    27.411697  
min            -16.347592   -25.266641   -28.377081  
25%             -1.100998    -0.632126    17.994602  
50%              0.010404     0.000000    33.423554  
75%              1.075803     0.785296    57.287054  
max             25.266641    16.347592   102.491103
```

Comment: Hi, Can you edit to question to add df summary data you are trying to plot ?

Comment: Hi I have added summary data

Comment: Hi, did you solve your issue ?